# How to Implement Mod tools for App level mods in Chat App

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a chat app with public rooms who have room mods, that can issue room bans. But for repeat offenders I want to have app mods that can ban from anywhere in the app. I get that I could implement a system of based on a threshold of reports, or just every report, But how would I show the mods the issue and avoid several mods working on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a pretty complex use-case to cover in a Stack Overflow answer. But basically you could:

- Store the reports in a collection in Firestore, each report being a document.
- Have each moderator monitor this collection, to alert them to issues.
- Write the moderator's UID into the report document when they start working on the report.

You app can *either* show all reports, but include the name of the moderator who's working on reports that are claimed, *or* it could filter the reports that somebody is already working on from the displayed list.a